# How to introduce microfrontend inside existing large scale app built using angular

Tags: micro-frontend

I have a react app that runs on 8081 port uses module federation plugin to expose the app to host.

I want to make angular app a host. How to setup entire architecture so that angular app can host components developed in react in its environment without loosing the essence of react core features.

Redux, LifeCycle hooks, contextAPI, Themes etc.

On the remote:

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
const packageJson = require("../package.json");
`your text`
const devConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8081/",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "AtlasReact",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./MarketingApp": "./src/bootstrap",
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

On the host:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'AtlasApp',
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'AtlasApp' },
      remotes: {
        AtlasReact: 'AtlasReact@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js',
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```